# How do I show only the value of the first orderdetail in MySQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

MYSQL version **5.7.38-google-log**

I have orders and orderdetails table. Follow this https://dbfiddle.uk/bdosg8aa

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
orderID int,
orderAmount int );

INSERT INTO orders(orderID,orderAmount) VALUES (1,10);
INSERT INTO orders(orderID,orderAmount) VALUES (2,5);
INSERT INTO orders(orderID,orderAmount) VALUES (3,8);

CREATE TABLE orderdetails (
orderdetailsID int, 
orderID int, 
itemID int);


INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderdetailsID,orderID,itemID) VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderdetailsID,orderID,itemID) VALUES (2,1,2);
INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderdetailsID,orderID,itemID) VALUES (3,1,3);
INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderdetailsID,orderID,itemID) VALUES (4,2,1);
INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderdetailsID,orderID,itemID) VALUES (5,2,2);
INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderdetailsID,orderID,itemID) VALUES (6,2,3);
INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderdetailsID,orderID,itemID) VALUES (7,3,1);
INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderdetailsID,orderID,itemID) VALUES (8,3,2);
INSERT INTO orderdetails(orderdetailsID,orderID,itemID) VALUES (9,3,3);
```

**DESIRE RESULT**

How do i make this (only show orderAmount for the first orderdetailid)

[image]

Comment: create a https://dbfiddle.uk/ with sample  data instead of using images

Comment: What version of MySQL? Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: What means „first“?